# Angular 6: Call a function inside an FormArray dynamically

Tags: angular, formarray

```
<tr *ngFor="let bidRequestDetail of (bidRequestsById.bidRequestDetails || bidResponseForm.get('bidResponseDetails').controls); let i=index">
                    <td class="table-primary">
                      <div><small>{{i+1}}</small></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-secondary">
                      <div><small>{{bidRequestDetail.product}}</small></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-primary">
                      <div><small>{{bidRequestDetail.description}}</small></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-secondary">
                      <div><small>{{bidRequestDetail.quantity}}({{bidRequestDetail.unit}})</small></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-primary">
                      <div><small>
                          <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i> {{bidRequestDetail.quotedAmount}}</small></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table`enter code here`-secondary">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <form formArrayName="bidResponseDetails" (click)="addbidResponseDetails()">
                          <div [formGroupName]="i">
                            <div class="input-group" #myDiv>
                              <input type="number" formControlName="quotedAmount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount {{i}}"
                                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && bidRequestDetail.controls.quotedAmount.errors }" />
                              <input type="number" formControlName="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="quantity"
                                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && bidRequestDetail.controls.quantity.errors }" />
                              <textarea type="text" formControlName="notes" class="form-control" placeholder="notes"
                                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && bidRequestDetail.controls.notes.errors }"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

I need to call a function, inside a formarray when a div tag loads.
(Click) event works i.e creates an array upon click. I need to trigger a function call dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically here `I need to trigger a function call dynamically.` ?

Comment: Hi pradeep, I meant call addbidResponseDetails()(without any click something like onload()) function  when the <div> tag loads which is under <form> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call your required function within the `afterViewInit` life cycle hook of component like below -

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addbidResponseDetails()
  }
}
```

I am using `AfterViewInit` hook here because it is

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after Angular has completed initialization of a component's view. It is invoked only once when the view is instantiated.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addbidResponseDetails()
  }   here addbidResponseDetails() will be called only once. My requirement is to call addbidResponseDetails() multiple times i.e upto the length of the array. You can find the array in *ngFor ( 1st line of the code).

Comment: addbidResponseDetails() {
    this.bidResponseDetails.push(this.createBidResponseDetails());
  }                      createBidResponseDetails(): FormGroup {
    console.log("create called");
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      bidRequestDetail: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      notes: '',
      quantity: '',
      quotedAmount: ''
    });
  }

Comment: Simply you can call same function in loop in the life cycle hook